# R Shiny Make slider value dynamic

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I've got a dropdown selector and a slider scale. I want to render a plot with the drop down selector being the source of data. - I've got this part working

I simply want the slider's max value to change based on which dataset is selected.

Any suggestions?

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

source("profile_plot.R")
load("test.Rdata")

output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
  if(input$selection == "raw") {
    plot_data <- as.matrix(obatch[1:input$probes,1:36])
  } else if(input$selection == "normalised") {
  plot_data <- as.matrix(eset.spike[1:input$probes,1:36])
  } 

  plot_profile(plot_data, treatments = treatment, sep = TRUE)
  })
})
```

**ui.R**
    library(shiny)

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Profile Plot"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width=3,
    selectInput("selection", "Choose a dataset:", 
                 choices=c('raw', 'normalised')),
    hr(),
    sliderInput("probes",
              "Number of probes:",
              min = 2,
              max = 3540,
              value = 10)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

Comment: Create the `sliderInput` dynamically in server.R using `renderUI`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully this post will help someone learning Shiny:

The information in the answers is useful conceptually and mechanically, but doesn't help the overall question.

So the most useful feature I found in the UI API is `conditionalPanel()` [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/conditionalPanel.html)

This means I could create a slider function for each dataset loaded and get the max value by loading in the data initially in `global.R`. For those that don't know, objects loaded into `global.R` can be referenced from `ui.R`.

**global.R** - Loads in a ggplo2 method and test data objects (eset.spike & obatch)

```
source("profile_plot.R")
load("test.Rdata")
```

**server.R** -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyIncubator)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues()

  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "Raw Data" = obatch,
           "Normalised Data - Pre QC" = eset.spike)
  })

  sepInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$sep,
           "Yes" = TRUE,
           "No" = FALSE)
  })

  rangeInput <- reactive({
    df <- datasetInput()
    values$range  <- length(df[,1])
    if(input$unit == "Percentile") {
      values$first  <- ceiling((values$range/100) * input$percentile[1])
      values$last   <- ceiling((values$range/100) * input$percentile[2])
    } else {
      values$first  <- 1
      values$last   <- input$probes      
    }
  })

  plotInput <- reactive({
    df     <- datasetInput()
    enable <- sepInput()
    rangeInput()
    p      <- plot_profile(df[values$first:values$last,],
                           treatments=treatment, 
                           sep=enable)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    print(plotInput())
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste(input$dataset, '_Data.csv', sep='') },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(datasetInput(), file)
    }
  )

  output$downloadRangeData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste(input$dataset, '_', values$first, '_', values$last, '_Range.csv', sep='') },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(datasetInput()[values$first:values$last,], file)
    }
  )

  output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste(input$dataset, '_ProfilePlot.png', sep='') },
    content = function(file) {
      png(file)
      print(plotInput())
      dev.off()
    }
  )

})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyIncubator)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Profile Plot'),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:", 
                choices = c("Raw Data", "Normalised Data - Pre QC")),

    selectInput("sep", "Separate by Treatment?:",
                choices = c("Yes", "No")),

    selectInput("unit", "Unit:",
                choices = c("Percentile", "Absolute")),


    wellPanel( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.unit == 'Percentile'",
        sliderInput("percentile", 
                    label = "Percentile Range:",
                    min = 1, max = 100, value = c(1, 5))
      ),

      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.unit == 'Absolute'",
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.dataset == 'Normalised Data - Pre QC'",
          sliderInput("probes",
                      "Probes:",
                      min = 1,
                      max = length(eset.spike[,1]),
                      value = 30)
        ),

        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.dataset == 'Raw Data'",
          sliderInput("probes",
                      "Probes:",
                      min = 1,
                      max = length(obatch[,1]),
                      value = 30)
        )
      )
    )
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot'), 
    wellPanel(
      downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download Data Set'),
      downloadButton('downloadRangeData', 'Download Current Range'),
      downloadButton('downloadPlot', 'Download Plot')
    )
  )
))
```

Answer (score 6):

As @Edik noted the best way to do this would be to use an `update..` type function. It looks like `updateSliderInput` doesnt allow control of the range so you can try using `renderUI` on the server side:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    numericInput('n', 'Maximum of slider', 100),
    uiOutput("slider"),
    textOutput("test")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$slider <- renderUI({
      sliderInput("myslider", "Slider text", 1,
                  max(input$n, isolate(input$myslider)), 21)
    })

    output$test <- renderText({input$myslider})
  }
))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the updateSliderInput function that allows you to programmatically update a shiny input:
http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/updateSliderInput.html. There are similar functions for other inputs as well.

```
 observe({
     x.dataset.selection = input$selection
     if (x.dataset.selection == "raw") {
        x.num.rows = nrow(obatch)
     } else {
        x.num.rows = nrow(eset.spike)
     }
     # Edit: Turns out updateSliderInput can't do this, 
     # but using a numericInput with 
     # updateNumericInput should do the trick.
     updateSliderInput(session, "probes",
       label = paste("Slider label", x.dataset.selection),
       value = c(1,x.num.rows))
 })
```

Comment: Also, if you put your expression sets in a list with names the same as the input "selection" it makes it much easier with more options.

Comment: `updateSliderInput` does not allow control of the maximum or minimum

Comment: Ah I guess you're right. updateNumericInput does have that capability though.

Comment: It would be nice if you could control max and min not sure why it is not available.

Comment: Setting max and min is a known issue https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/147 . it appears not to be possible to remove and add back a slider, in order to change min/max/step hence `updateSliderInput` doesnt have this feature

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative can be applying a renderUI approach like it is described in one of the shiny gallery examples:

http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/dynamic-ui.html