# Why I have to load packages and files before run a shiny app in R?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I would like to know why when I open a shiny app in r-studio I have to run all packages and files before run it the app. I would like just clic in the run app botton and that everything be loaded automatically. Is there a clean solution for this?

This is the error I have:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4659
Warning: Error in dropNulls: object 'df1' not found
  61: dropNulls
  60: getSliderType
  59: sliderInput
```

df1 is a excel file and the code is in server.R in shinyServer(function(input, output) {})

```
df1=data.frame(read_excel("C:/Users/Desktop/Prueba/Base.xlsx", sheet = "1.1.1"))
```

and

`library(readxl)`

is before the "shinyServer(....)"

Comment: You can have the library calls at the top of your shiny app if you'd like.  That would save you having the call them manually.  When you say `library(readxl` is before `shinyServer(...)` what exactly do you mean?  It needs to be before the call to `read_excel`.

Comment: The error you posted doesn't seem to come from the code you posted. You seem to define `df1` locally inside this `renderPlotly` call, but the error seems to come from a responsive `sliderInput`. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @Greg you can see my server.R code in a edit

Comment: @MrFlick you can se my ui and server code in a edit

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111290/r-shiny-make-slider-value-dynamic. The `df1` variables doesn't exist in your `ui.R` file. You would need to create a reactive element on the server and update the UI after you load your data.

Comment: thks! With a global.R file where I have all packages and files it resolves.

Comment: @JRN you can make that into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It resolves creating a global.R file in the same direction that ui.R and server.R.
Thks to MrFlick for the information.